# SvcUtil.exe - generate separate file for each class in wsdl

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, svcutil.exe

Is it possible using **SvcUtil.exe** to generate separate file for each class in wsdl schema defination.

Comment: not possible, and not needed, since it is just generated codes which generally you don't need to read or maintain manually. BTW, why do you want separated files?

Comment: To support the multiple versions of same wsdl, i want to have common classes between them generated one time and different classes generated separately for each version.

Comment: Do you want co-existence of versions of the Web service, and have respective client proxies for each version of the service?

Comment: There will be one proxy wrapper for number of web service versions. A common WCF client will be used with different URL and Version specific  APIs are managed again with common Interface on top of default proxy interface.

Comment: If you let each version of the service publish their own WSDL respectively, you will then create client wrappers separately.

Comment: web services are PHP based from 3rd party service provider.

Comment: then according to the user manual of svcutil.exe, you won't be able to create multiple wrapper files for multiple versions of the service defined in one WSDL.